# Reading data from a txt file and getting a permission denied in terminal

Tags: c, ssh, terminal, text-files, zsh

I'm hoping that I'm missing something simple because I've got to submit this lab before 4 pm EST tomorrow.

I'm accessing my account from SSH Secure Shell and while I was at school I could run the command `mergeSort < data` and it would sort the numbers, however I try to run the same command here at my home and I get: `zsh: permission denied: data`. I've also used the `make` command in conjunction with the file they provide with the lab that does:

```
#;-*-Makefile-*-
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
CC = gcc
all: insertionSort mergeSort

insertionSort: sortDriver.o metrics.o insertionSort.o
    gcc -o insertionSort sortDriver.o metrics.o insertionSort.o

mergeSort: sortDriver.o metrics.o mergeSort.o
    gcc -o mergeSort sortDriver.o metrics.o mergeSort.o

testMetrics: metrics.c
    gcc -o testMetrics -Wall -D TEST_METRICS metrics.c
    @-./testMetrics
    @-rm metrics.o core testMetrics 2> /dev/null

clean:
    -@rm -f *~ *.o a.out core insertionSort mergeSort *.exe
```

I tried re-create the file outside of it and when transfer it all it says is

> encountered 1 errors during the transfer

It will still show up, but still wont open and when I double click on it the same message as above pops up.

The permissions of related files, there are more but I suppose these are the most relevant for the task at hand.

```
data attributes -rwxrwxrwx
data.txt attributes -rwxrwxrwx
mergeSort.c attributes -rw-r--r--
mergeSort.o attributes -rw-------
mergeSort attributes -rwxrwxrwx
```

I have attempted the following, i feel as though r/w/x is what i need and can change it around after I've fixed the problem.

for almost all files, or at least for all files listed above i've put

```
% chmod 777 {file name}
% make
% mergeSort < data   (tried .txt as well)
```

But i still get:

```
% zsh: permission denied: mergeSort
```

Comment: Can you check permission of mergeSort?

Comment: Please check..http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46767/executing-a-script-in-zsh-file-permissions

Comment: I've added the permissions above, I've also down some researching after I read the link you sent me, thanks btw, so i've learned the cmmd chmod however there are many different ways of changing the permissions and i'm unsure of which is working

Comment: I feel as though I might maybe be missing a command i.e someone used **sudo chmod -R -v 775 2013-14** but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things:

First, set the permissions to sane values:

> $ chmod 600 data data.txt
>
> $ chmod 700 mergeSort

Second, run the program with a relative path:

> $ ./mergeSort < data

or

> $ cat data | ./mergeSort

Good luck!

Comment: So far no dice. I've used the commands that you've suggested but it still comes up with 'zsh: permission denied: mergeSort'. I've tried starting from scratch, maybe there was a glitch, unzipped the stock folder from my schools system, change the permissions, and same thing.

the executable file that should run, on my computer just show a blank page as it's icon, but on linux system.. well it had a different icon. I don't think this is the issue, computer being able to tell it's an executable here, but am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the system you're trying to run the program on doesn't allow you to execute your own programs. Check the permissions on the file system mount.